# How to create a sparse matrix from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have sparse data in dataframe. How can I create a sparse matrix from it and in which models I can use it for predictions?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10, 10)))
df.iloc[5, 5] = 1

df

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

Memmory Usage: 880
```

You can make it sparse with `to_sparse(0)`.
The first argument is the value to assume is the filler value.

```
d1 = df.to_sparse(0)

d1

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

Memmory Usage: 88
```

The memory footprint is a 10th the size.

Comment: Note: `pd.DataFrame.to_sparse()` has been deprecated since 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will keep the data as sparse as possible and avoids memory issues.  The csr_matrix is a standard sparse matrix format that can be used with scipy and sklearn for modeling.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse
df = pd.DataFrame({'rowid':[1,2,3,4,5], 'val1':[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'val2':[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})
print 'Input data frame\n{0}'.format(df)
print 'DataFrame to a sparse matrix'
df_as_sparse_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(df.as_matrix())
print df_as_sparse_matrix.todense()
```